How do I save hover effect on an item in the rc-menu library?
Good afternoon! Our project uses the rc-menu library to build a drop-down list. My task is to save the hover effect on an element when the user moves the cursor outside the drop-down list. I can't figure out how to do this? Has anyone encountered such a problem? Can you tell me the solution?
I tried to set onMouseLeave on the Menu item but it didn't help. He has his own listener under the hood, which overlaps mine. I don't understand how to manipulate an element

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
